# Can't get input value from other page

Tags: php, jquery, session

I want to get input value from other page and why it's not working?

Here is the code:

Page 1:

```
<h1 align="center">
    <form name="form" action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="wonorlose" id="wonorlose" value="50">
    </form>
</h1>
```

On button click:

```
<script>
    function rollHead(){
        var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if(d1 == 1)
        {
            die1.innerHTML = "You lose!";
            fliped.innerHTML = "Fliped Tail!";
            var getsession = new XMLHttpRequest();
            getsession.open('POST','getsession.php',true);
            getsession.send();
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open('POST','lose.php',true);
            ajax.send();
        }
        else if (d1 == 2)
        {
            die1.innerHTML = "You won!";
            fliped.innerHTML = "Fliped Head!";
            var getsession = new XMLHttpRequest();
            getsession.open('POST','getsession.php',true);
            getsession.send();
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open('POST','won.php',true);
            ajax.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Page ajax.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: /manopuslapis/index.php");
    }
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $_SESSION['wonorlose'] = $wonorlose;
    echo $wonorlose;
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET credits=credits+'$wonorlose' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']); 
?>
```

Page getsession.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
     header("Location: /manopuslapis/index.php");
    }
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $_SESSION['wonorlose'] = $_GET["wonorlose"];
?>
```

P.S roll system works and I get message won or lose but nothing happens in my database. If i change page 2 `$winorlose` to number, it works.

There might be something wrong with the sessions, I think.

Comment: have you started the session?

Comment: You can't mix javascript and PHP. PHP runs before the page loads, javascript runs after. If you want to update the session, you'll need to send an ajax call to a PHP page.

Comment: `money=money+'$wonorlose'` should be at least `money=money+'" . $wonorlose . "'`, what is even still bad ...

Comment: if u see I call it on function roolhead @aynber

Comment: @NiekasNiekas  Yes, but that's inside a javascript function. PHP has already parsed out the page and finished by the time the button is pressed. If $_GET is empty when the page is loaded, then the session will be empty. If you want to update the session when the button is pressed, you need to use ajax to send a request back to the server.

Comment: look up updated code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a session like this:

```
<script>
function rollHead(){
    .....
    <?php
    $_SESSION['wonorlose'] = $_GET["wonorlose"];
    ?>
......
}
```

because php runs at the time of html parsing on browser. So technically there is no session saved with the name "wonorlose".

In this case you have to make an ajax call to create a session and another call to read it.

Comment: but if i create other page that have this function: $_SESSION['wonorlose'] = $_GET["wonorlose"]; how it will get varriable value, because it's still on page 1

Comment: You have to make an ajax call to create the session and than on your Page 2 you will get it by using $_SESSION['wonorlose'] = $wonorlose;

Comment: I created this and it's not working i call it on roolhead <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: /manopuslapis/index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$_SESSION['wonorlose'] = $_GET["wonorlose"];
?>

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['wonorlose'] = $wonorlose;
echo $wonorlose;
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET money=money+'$wonorlose' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
```

Comment: echo this `"UPDATE users SET money=money+$wonorlose WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'] and what result?

Comment: if i change mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET money=money+'$wonorlose' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']); to money=money+10 WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']); it works and adds +10 money